# How to apply maxlength property using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a kendo ui control that create following html syntax on runtime

```
<input id=​"ItemSearch" name=​"ItemSearch" style=​"width:​115px;​" type=​"text">​
```

How can I apply the maxlength HTML5 property to it using javascript

When I use following I am getting `Cannot call method 'prop' of undefined`

```
 $('#ItemSearch').input.prop("maxlength", 2);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `.input` as `$('#ItemSearch')` has already selected that element. Try this:

```
$('#ItemSearch').prop("maxlength", 2);
```

Comment: Thanks   `$('#ItemSearch').prop("maxlength", 2);` worked.  Key point - maxlength should be in double quotes; not single quotes

Comment: @pratapk not true, both single and double quotes are entirely valid in javascript.